# Productionize Data pipeline

Tags: data-engineering

Data engineering pipeline productionize

Hello everyone!
I am new to the field of data engineering, and wanted to understand how are data engineering pipelines productionized/deployed in general?

E.g - I have a code base written in pyspark which ingests data, transforms logic and stores into target database. I might use airflow to orchestrate it daily.

But how do I actually go ahead and productionize the ETL pipeline?

I am looking for a software engineering parallel for this